# Cannot increase the gap between raised button

Tags: flutter

**I put height inside the under sizedbox also cannot change the gap**

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;
  final String answerText;<

  const Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedButton(    
          color: const Color(0xFF29B6F6),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text(
            answerText,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
          onPressed: selectHandler,
       ), //RaisedButton
      );
}
```

[this the output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxq5G.png)

Comment: it would be helpful to share code snippet where you call the answer button

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Container()` instead of `SizedBox()` and inside container give margin: `EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0)`

```
Container(
     margin:EdgeInserts.only(bottom:12.0),
 )
```